# Как правильно: ярое подтверждение или яркое?

Tags: словообразование

*Три обгоревших ствола некогда мощных сосен были тому ярким (ярым) подтверждением.*

*Большой интерес посетителей к представленным решениям являлся ярым (ярким) тому подтверждением.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно ***ярким подтверждением***. "Ярый" от слова *"яростный",* [вот](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x) его значения:

> 1. Испытывающий сильный гнев, ожесточение; полный ярости (о человеке, животном);
> 2. Неукротимый, неистовый (о стихиях, явлениях природы);
> 3. Чрезмерный, необычайный по силе, интенсивности, степени своего проявления;
> 4. **только полн.** Страстно преданный кому-, чему-л., убеждённый в чём-л., увлекающийся чем-л.; пылкий.

Answer (score 2):

***Яркое подтверждение.***

Одно из значений слова "яркий" - 4) такой, который производит сильное впечатление своей убедительностью, выразительностью и т.п.; такой, который убеждает в чём-либо, убедительный. Сочетается: *...пример чего-либо, иллюстрация чего-либо, доказательство чего-либо...*

[Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка](http://padaread.com/?book=30721&pg=685)